# SQL Trigger performance vs Change data capture

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, cdc

In my SQL Server 2012 database there are 260 triggers (150 line each) on 160 tables for auditing data change in to three user tables.

Is it good to go with built-in Change Data Capture option having 160 audit tables for 160 tables or was the above approach correct?

Comment: I am using microsoft sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

CDC works slightly different: it serially reads transaction log and fills history tables. Thus history writes occur delayed and do not linger original DML transaction. However CDC tables are controlled by methods you can not control and if you would like, for example, to append some additional column which is not mapped to any data column from original table - that would be a challenge.

Triggers you described or stored procs performing the same actions are good enough. Usually they are produced by code-generation methods and do not complicate developer's life.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, you say that your history of 160 tables is stored in 3 tables - this is also impossible to make with CDC. Which is obviously neither bad nor good.